# I am trying to use php file() and pull from another directory and use an * in the filename

Tags: php

I am trying to use the file () function to read a file into an array from another directory. The directory would be at ../data. Also need to read the file in as anything beginning with PaymentPlanExport*. I will be reading these in monthly and only one file will be in that directory at a time. The only difference between the file are the date.

```
$records = file("PaymentPlanExport*");
```

Comment: What makes you think PHP would let you potentially open multiple files as one resource? Read the docs and change `"PaymentPlanExport*"` to a single file path.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all matching files and then in the resulting array find the file you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` doesn't support wildcards. If you need wildcard support for file operations in php, you could use the `glob` function, which returns a array of all matching file.

In your case, you could simply use `file(glob('PaymentPlanExport*')[0])` - but I would recommend to add some checks, if the file really exists.

```
$pattern = '../data/PaymentPlanExport*';
$files = glob($pattern);
if (count($files) != 1) {
    // error handling
}
$f = fopen($files[0]);
```

Comment: I only want to open one file at a time. There will be only one file in that directory and then will get moved to an archive directory.

Comment: I did not fully understand your post before I posted my last comment. Thank you, that makes since.